# Python: Algorithm to walk all the integers in a list and come up with all possible values?

Tags: python, algorithm

```
list = [0,0,...0]
```

look at the last placeholder in the list, increment it by one.

```
[0,0,...1]
[0,0,...2]
[0,0,...3]
..
..
[0,0,...82] #stop at the last integer in range from 1 to 89 (randomly generated)
```

increment it up to a random integer range value from 1 to 100
Once the last place value is at the end of the range, reset this placeholder to zero, move to previous placeholder and increment and then look at the next place holder and repeat what we did above.

```
[0,0,..1,0]
[0,0,..1,1]
[0,0,..1,2]
[0,0,..1,3]
..
..
[0,0,..1,77]
##################

[0,0,..2,0]
[0,0,..2,1]
[0,0,..2,2]
[0,0,..2,3]
..
..
[0,0,..2,41]
##################

[0,0,..1,0,0]
[0,0,..1,0,1]
[0,0,..1,0,2]
[0,0,..1,1,0]
[0,0,..1,1,1]
[0,0,..1,1,2]
[0,0,..1,1,3]
[0,0,..1,1,0]
[0,0,..1,2,0]
[0,0,..1,2,1]
[0,0,..1,2,2]
[0,0,..2,0,0]
[0,0,..2,0,1]
[0,0,..2,1,0]
[0,0,..2,1,1]
[0,0,..2,1,2]
[0,0,..2,1,3]
[0,0,..2,1,4]
##################
```

This keeps going until all the integer in the list have been incremented.

Comment: You're going to need to explain this a bit more clearly. Are the lists filled with `0`s? How many?

Comment: @jozzas, it's filled with constant number of items. Each list will contain N number of 0s, where N is equal to 1 or greater.

Comment: That is a possible homework and there appears no effort in solving it. Try some solutions and ask more specific questions if you had.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Set `listLen` to be the number of `int`s you want in your list to begin with

```
listLen = 10 # generate lists of length 10
low = 0 # the lower bound of the numbers you want to walk
high = random.randint(0,100) # the upper bound of the numbers you want to walk
for L in itertools.product(range(low, high+1), repeat=listLen):
  print(L)
```

If you want to choose a different random number of each list, then you could do this instead:

```
listLen = 10
low = 0
for L in itertools.product(*[range(low,random.randint(0,100)) for _ in range(listLen)]):
  print(L)
```

Comment: I believe he wants to use a *different* random number every time you reset the unit. What you wrote simply chooses one at the beginning.

Comment: @Bakuriu: hrm... good point. Check out the edit!

Comment: ho ho ho ho ho this is so much win

Comment: @inspectorG4dget yes I was waiting for the countdown to end until I could accept it

Comment: @ILovePython: no sweat! I almost always post that comment for users with <100 rep